# Taylor Series Expansion of $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $ around $ a = 4 $

Tags: taylor-expansion

guys.

Here's the exercise: find a series representation for the function $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $ around $ a = 4 $ and find it's radius of convergence.

My doubt is on the first part: I can't seem to find a pattern.

$ \circ f(x) = \sqrt x \rightarrow f(4) = 2 \\ \circ f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \rightarrow f'(4) = \frac{1}{4} \\ \circ f''(x) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right) \cdot x^{-\frac{3}{2}} \rightarrow f''(4) = \frac{-1}{4 \cdot 8} = \frac{-1}{4 \cdot (2 \cdot 4^1)} = \frac{-1}{2 \cdot 4^2} \\\\ \circ f^{(3)}(x) = -\frac{1}{4} \cdot \left(- \frac{3}{2} \right) \cdot x^{-\frac{5}{2}} \rightarrow f^{(3)}(4) = \frac{3}{4 \cdot 32} = \frac{3}{4 \cdot (4^2 \cdot 2)} = \frac{3}{4^3 \cdot 2} \\\\ \circ f^{(4)}(x) = \frac{3}{8} \cdot \left(- \frac{5}{2} \right) \cdot x^{-\frac{7}{2}} \rightarrow f^{(4)}(4) = \frac{-3 \cdot 5}{4 \cdot 128} = -\frac{3 \cdot 5}{4 \cdot (4^3 \cdot 2)} = -\frac{3 \cdot 5}{4^4 \cdot 2} $

hmm.. Can I say then that:

$ f(x) = 2 + \frac{(x-4)}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \cdot (1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dots (2n-3)) \cdot (x-4)^n}{4^n} $ and using the ratio test:

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(x-4)^{n+1} \cdot (2n-1)}{4^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{4^n}{(x-4)^n \cdot (2n-3)} \right| = \frac{|x-4|}{4} \rightarrow -4 < x-4 < 4 \therefore 0 < x < 8 $ and thus R = 4.

But here's the thing: the answer on the book is:

$ 2 + \frac{(x-4)}{4} + 2 \cdot \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \cdot \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dots (2n-3)  \cdot (x-4)^n}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \dots (2n) \cdot 4^n} $

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  We have for $n\ge 2$

$$\begin{align}
f^{(n)}(x)&=(-1)^{n-1}\frac12 \frac12 \frac32 \frac52 \cdots \frac{2n-3}{2}x^{-(2n-1)/2}\\\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{2^n}x^{-(2n-1)/2}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

where $(2n-3)!! = 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot (2n-3)$ is the double factorial of $2n-3$.  Evaluating $(1)$ at $x=4$ yields

$$f^{(n)}(4)=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2(2n-3)!!}{2^n4^n}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=f(4)=f'(4)(x-4)+2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2^n)(4^n)n!}(x-4)^n\\\\
&=2+\frac{(x-4)}{4}+2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!(4^n)}(x-4)^n\\\\
\end{align}$$

where $(2^n)n!=(2n)!!=2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots 2n$ and again $(2n-3)!!=1\cdot3\cdot 5\cdots(2n-3)$.  And we are done!

Comment: I can't really see where I messed up, mate. Could you explain it to me? 

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  First, the definition of the double factorial is indeed $(2n-3)!!=(2n-3)(2n-1)\cdots (3)(1)$ and certainly not $(1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-3))!$.  Second, I believe that by substituting early for $x=4$, as you seemed to have done, and simplifying terms prematurely, one can lose the forest for the trees.  In the development herein, notice that we first establish the pattern for $f^{(n)}(x)$ and then substitute $x=4$ thereafter.  This approach provides a tractable way forward.

Comment: I see. Very nice analogy, :D. I believe I'll stick to finding the patterns first from now on. 

But here's the thing: while I do see how your answer is correct, I can't exactly pinpoint the mistake on mine. I do believe it is because I substituted too early, but I don't know where the mistake is.

Anyways, thanks a lot, mate! Have a good night.

Comment: @PedroCunha And you are most welcome Pedro!  - Mark

Comment: Hey, mate. Just stopping by to thank you one more time! I did the exercise once more, this time on my own and I really understood it. Also, the notion of double factorial is a neat new addition to my "repertoire".
Really appreciate the patience!

Have a good one.

Comment: Hey Pedro.  I enjoyed our discussion.  And really pleased to hear that you've worked it out for yourself.  - Mark